# Get valid path chars for current OS / Filter invalid chars from path string

Tags: java, cross-platform

I want to check if a string containing a path is legal or not.

What does not work:

- I could use a regex and replace invalid chars for a specific OS (like Windows); That would only work on a single specific OS
- I could use Java 7's NIO `Paths.get()` and catch the exception, but that would only say whether the path is valid or not, I want to *remove* invalid chars.

I only found sources on the internet that did one of the above things. What would be awesome would be something like `getInvalidChars()` in a standard library which would give me a list of system-dependent invalid chars (or the exact opposite, `getAllowedChars()` or something like that).

The Java version does not matter.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If it serves as consolation, the InvalidPathException generated by Paths.get() does return the position of the offending char on its getIndex() method. Maybe that could serve as a basis for a (super slow) character checker...

Comment: I'll check how slow it is, it does not have to be fast.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.getProperty("os.name")` to get the OS. So you could do something like this:

```
String os = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
if (os.indexOf("win") >= 0)
    invalidChars("win");
else if (os.indexOf("mac") >= 0)
    invalidChars("mac");
else if (os.indexOf("linux") >= 0)
    invalidChars("linux");
```

The `invalidChars(String os)` function would then remove the invalid chars depending on the OS given.

Comment: Thank you, but I hoped there would be a proper solution where I do not have to make a list of chars by myself...